# How to use namespace inside create_function (or eval)?

Tags: php, cakephp, laravel

I'm looking at some PHP code where there is no other option but to use `create_function` or `eval` inside the code (the code is somewhat dynamic).

Anyway, my question is **how can I use namespaces inside the `evaled` code?**

**Code that works:**

```
$code = "return \Core\Model\Permission::Something;";
create_function('$test', $code); //Works! :)
```

**Code that does not work:**

```
$code = "return Permission::Something;"; 
create_function('$test', "use \Core\Model\Permission; " . $code); //Doesn't Work :(

ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)
```

How can I modify my code so that when someone refers to `Permission` class in create_function (or eval), it automatically refers the `\Core\Model\Permission` class?

Comment: Creating functions on-the-fly, like this, is very bad practice. You should seriously consider alternative solutions that do not involve `eval`ing stuff.

Comment: hi, i know.. but due to the nature of this app there is no other option.. the good thing is the code runs in a sandbox and can't be accessed via web.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen is right, I'm pretty sure there is a better way to solve whatever you try to do. Also why is this tagged with CakePHP *and* Laravel?

Comment: Regardless, the original question still stands. How to you refer to namespaces inside eval or create_function without specifying the whole path?

Comment: @supersan `create_function` was added to the language about 15 years ago. Namespaces were added only a couple of years ago. It is quite likely that the function does not even support namespaces (but I could be wrong). If you read the docs then it says you should use a *"native anonymous function"* instead, which is good advice.

Comment: i guess you're right about the fact that namespaces were added much later after eval or create_function, but then here is the issue: if it wasn't supported then something like this won't work:

     "return \Core\Model\Permission::Something;"

but it does. so you could be right it may not be supported but i just wanted to confirm for sure, or if there is way it is.

Comment: You may be out of luck here, first of all `use` statements are [**not allowed in block scopes**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope), they are being processed at compile time, so you would have to place it outside of the function at namespace or class declaration scope, however functions created with `create_function` seem to run in a weird global scope where it cannot pick up imported classes, whereas normal functions can. **http://codepad.viper-7.com/zIidwb**